# Mapping dataflow creating output files in root directory irrespective of given dataset path

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I am trying to split a file having month data into separate day wise files using dataflow. 
I am storing the filename as a derived column and using this column as fileName in sink settings as shown below. The filename in the column is like Transactions_[date].csv

[image]

Then i am partitioning the file based on this column in optimise -> partition type- key -> Unique value per partition ->key column -> fileName

[image]

PROBLEM:
The dataflow runs perfectly. I can see the temporary files in my desired location during runtime but after completion, the files end up in the root location(inside container) and not inside my desired folder.

[image]

[image]

Update:
Dataset settings (hardcoded now but will be using dataset param)
[image]

Comment: The Partition should just be for the file name, not the folder - can you show the sink's DataSet settings?

Comment: Yeah sure @Joel.

Comment: Thanks - can you also show the Sink tab from the first screen shot?